# String trim and split

Tags: powershell, parsing, split, trim

I have a text file that I read and I need to get the values from.

Example text file:

```
[Site 01]
DBServer=LocalHost
DBName=Database01
Username=admin
Password=qwerty

[Site 02]
DBServer=192.168.0.10
DBName=Database02
Username=admin
Password=qwerty
```

Currently my code reads through the file and places each each as an array entry for each line `DBServer=` that is found and this text file can have many sites:

```
$NumOfSites = Get-Content $Sites |
              Select-String -Pattern "DBServer=" -Context 0,3
$i = 0
$NumOfSites | ForEach-Object {
    $svr  = $NumOfSites[$i] -isplit "\n" |
            % { ($_ -isplit 'DBServer=').Trim()[1] }
    $db   = $NumOfSites[$i] -isplit "\n" |
            % { ($_ -isplit 'DBName='.Trim())[1] }
    $uid  = $NumOfSites[$i] -isplit "\n" |
            % { ($_ -isplit 'Username='.Trim())[1] }
    $pswd = $NumOfSites[$i] -isplit "\n" |
            % { ($_ -isplit 'Password='.Trim())[1] }
    $i = $i+1
}
```

I can't get each attribute to split out properly without some extra spaces or something nicely as a string variable.
I just need to extract the info to put into an SQL connection line as variables from the format of the file example I have.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. Please make sure your code is a [mcve] when posting a question. Also, some of the parentheses seem to be misplaced, although that shouldn't break the code. With that said, parsing INI-style files is a pretty well-solved problem. Please do some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+parse+ini).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the record headers (i.e. `[Site 01]`) the rest can be handled by `ConvertFrom-StringData` just fine. We can just convert the records to objects directly splitting on the header row more or less. `ConvertFrom-StringData` turns a multi-line string into a hashtable, and you can just cast that as a `[PSCustomObject]` and viola, you have objects that are easy to use.

```
$NumOfSites = Get-Content $Sites -raw
$SiteObjects = $NumOfSites -split '\[.+?\]'|%{[PSCustomObject](ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_)}
```

Then you can manipulate `$SiteObjects` however you see fit (output to CSV if you want, or filter on any property using `Select-Object`). Or, if you're looking to make connections you can loop through it building your connections as needed...

```
ForEach($Connection in $SiteObjects){
    $ConStr = "Server = {0}; Database = {1}; Integrated Security = False; User ID = {2}; Password = {3};" -f $Connection.DBServer.Trim(), $Connection.DBName.Trim(), $Connection.Username.Trim(), $Connection.Password.Trim()
    <Do stuff with SQL>
}
```

**Edit:** Updating my answer since the sample text was changed to add `<pre>` and `</pre>`. We just need to remove those, and since the OP is getting errors about methods on null values we'll filter for null as well.

```
$NumOfSites = Get-Content $Sites -raw
$SiteObjects = $NumOfSites -replace '<.*?>' -split '\[.+?\]' | ?{$_} |%{[PSCustomObject](ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_)}
ForEach($Connection in $SiteObjects){ 
    $svr = $Connection.DBServer.Trim() 
    $db  = $Connection.DBName.Trim() 
    $uid = $Connection.Username.Trim() 
    $pwd = $Connection.Password.Trim()
}
```

Comment: Here this nice idea +1 needed the `-raw` parameter for the gc.

Comment: Ah, yes, I've updated the answer to include the `-raw` switch for `Get-Content`. Thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: I tried this but it sems to only fill the $Connection var after the first round and i get errors about You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: $NumOfSites = Get-Content $Sites -raw
    $SiteObjects = $NumOfSites -split '\[.+?\]'|%{[PSCustomObject](ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_)}

ForEach($Connection in $SiteObjects){
    
    $svr = $Connection.DBServer.Trim()
    $db = $Connection.DBName.Trim()
    $uid = $Connection.Username.Trim()
    $pwd = $Connection.Password.Trim()

Comment: Error on the First iteration repeats for each var i create:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\catalyph\Documents\PowerShell\SQLExecute\SQLexecute105 TEST.ps1:134 char:5
+     $svr = $Connection.DBServer.Trim()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I'm pretty sure the errors were regarding the `<pre>` and `</pre>` lines, as well as possibly null values or empty strings being passed. My update to my answer should address those issues. If you have further issues I thing it's related to file format compared to the sample given.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion if you only care about getting the value after the equals:

```
Get-Content Example.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
      Switch -Regex ($_) {
          'dbs.+=' { $svr = ($_ -replace '.+=').Trim()
          .. etc ..
      }
  }
```

`Get-Content` piped to `ForEach-Object` will interpret each line as its own object.

---

Edit:
You were most of the way there, but it's unnecessary to `-split` the lines

```
$NumOfSites = Get-Content $Sites | Select-String -pattern "DBServer=" -Context 0,3
$NumOfSites | ForEach-Object {
    Switch -Wildcard ($_) {
        'DBS*=' { $svr = ($_ -replace '.+=').Trim() }
        'DBN*=' { $db  = ($_ -replace '.+=').Trim() }
        'U*='   { $uid = ($_ -replace '.+=').Trim() }
        'P*='   { $pw  = ($_ -replace '.+=').Trim() }
    }
}
```

Comment: This captured the first site variables, but then kept them and they did not change in the next loop return.